# Как узнать какие есть файлы на сайте?

Tags: php, http, ftp

Есть сайт на котором есть файлы .ТХТ
но путь к ним не известный и название файлов тоже.

Как узнать путь к файлам и их название для того чтоб их скачать или посмотреть ?

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае такую информацию узнать нельзя, т.к. обычно выставлена защита на сайтах от перечисления папок и получения списка файлов. Только если включена возможность перечисления папок, что бывает редко, тогда можно набрать имя папки в браузере, например mysite.org/folder_name/, и возможно оно выдаст список файлов. Если список получать нельзя у папки, можно только перебирать возможные папки и имена и пытатьтся скачивать их.

Также можно попробовать поискать в гугле через "site:SITENAME filetype:txt" (например [найти все TXT на archive.org](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=site%3Aarchive.org%20filetype%3Atxt)), он вернёт список всех индексированных TXT файлов на заданном сайте, конечно если на них какая-то страница сайта где-то ссылалась, если ссылок на файлы нигде нет на страницах то и гугл не найдёт.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, я тоже думаю что это дело слишком сложное. Но если есть возможность сделать перебор и найти файлы то как это сделать ?

Comment: @user269585 Для начала нужно проверить в Гугле как я сказал, а вдруг  случайно ссылки на эти файлы где-то светились, может на самом сайте, а может на каком-то другом. Вы проверяли Гуглом уже? Перебирать почти нереально все возможности, нужно что-то знать о возможных именах папок и файлов, иначе всё пространство возможных имён насчитывает триллионы возможностей. Если есть какие-то идеи о том какими могут быть имена, то можно перебрать только их, можно это автоматизировать на каком-нибудь языке программирования, просто в цикле формируешь URL возможный и пытаешься его качать.

Comment: Вот то что вы говорите про то чтоб скачать с конкретной папки, и начать перебор имен есть истина.

Comment: А через Гугл ничего нет так как нет сылки на файл на самом сайте.